# Deploying with Spinnaker to App Engine from GitLab

Tags: google-app-engine, gitlab, spinnaker

I'm trying to know if there's any way to deploy a Google App Engine application, using Spinnaker with a repository that's on GitLab. I've already done the deploy from the repo on github, and it works like a charm, but my official repo is on GitLab (on premise gitlab installation). Is there any way to configure Spinnaker to connect to GitLab?

So far, I've read that a workaround could be used by Jenkins, but I would like to avoid it (would only do this for a very extreme case).

I've also came with the idea of putting a proxy, just set the webhook on gitlab, parse the json paylod to the github format, and sendit to Spinnaker, but also, that woulb be in case that's no way for Spinnaker to do it naturally

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spinnaker does not support webhooks from GitLab.

Adding support should not take much work. You're welcome to make a feature [request](http://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker) or implement support yourself - take a look at the [Echo](http://github.com/spinnaker/echo) microservice.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i'm gonna do both, the feature request and give it a try to implement that. Regards!